# SpecFlow ScenarioContext.Current is always returning null

Tags: specflow

I am trying to insert a value in ScenarioContext.Current but for some reason ScenarioContext.Current is null.

Answer (score 7):

If you're in a [BeforeFeature], have you tried using FeatureContext.Current instead?

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that ScenarioContext.Current is null inside [BeforeFeature], which was not what I initially expected. Where are you calling ScenarioContext.Current from?